# Page Jumps on jQuery change();

Tags: jquery, page-jump

I'm using couple buttons to toggle divs. Whenever I click on the button, the page jumps.

Any ideas?

Here's my markup:

```
  <label class='radio btn'>
    <input checked='checked' id='donation_payment_type_eft' name='donation[payment_type]' type='radio' value='eft'>
    <span class='payment-type-echeck' style='background-position: -413px 0;'>ECheck</span>
  </label>
  <label class='radio btn'>
    <input id='donation_payment_type_cc' name='donation[payment_type]' type='radio' value='cc'>
    <ul class='card_logos'>
      <li class='card_visa'>Visa</li>
      <li class='card_mastercard'>Mastercard</li>
      <li class='card_amex'>American Express</li>
      <li class='card_discover'>Discover</li>
    </ul>
  </label>
```

and my jQuery:

```
$('#donation_payment_type_eft, #donation_payment_type_cc').change(function(e) {    
 $('.eft_donation').toggle();
 $('.cc_donation').toggle();
 e.preventDefault();
 return false;
});
```

Comment: You're removing elements from the document flow, what do you expect?

Comment: I dropped provided logic into a page and did not see a jump. Maybe if you provide the full markup or a link to the page it would help sort this out.

Comment: Here's the full markup: https://gist.github.com/6b6cb6f7d44e6a3ebe54

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that steps:

1. remove display:none in div that have class cc_donation
2. calculate max height value and specify for divs that calculated value like this:

_

```
$(function(){
            var eft_height = $(".eft_donation").height();
            var cc_height = $(".cc_donation").height();
            var max = Math.max(eft_height, cc_height);
            $(".eft_donation, .cc_donation").height(max);
            $(".cc_donation").hide();
        });
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with this.

Could you walk me through your thoughts?

Comment: I paste your markup from github and notice that your page is jumps when when radio selected. That behavior occurs because your divs don't have a same height, you should set to divs equal height and your jumping go away